# Different order of bases in terminology of transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be vector space with two basis $U=(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ and $V=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$ and denote 
$M$ the matrix associated to the identity map $E\longrightarrow E$ where the domain $E$ is with basis $U=(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ and the codomain $E$ is with basis $V=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$.

My question: Why in frensh litterature we call $M$ the transition matrix from $V$ to $U$ (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_de_passage ) and in the english litterature we call this the transition matrix from $U$ to $V$, although both give the same definition of the matrix $M$, that is the the $i-$th columnn of $M$ is $m_i=(m_{1i},\cdots,m_{ni})$ given by the coefficients of $u_i=m_{1i}v_1+\cdots+m_{ni}v_n$.

Comment: I think this may upset you a little, but these are really two absolutely same definitions. Just different words in different languages.

Comment: Absolutely same definitions but opposite words, in frensh this is a transition matrix from $V$ to $U$ while in english this is a transition matrix from $U$ to $V$ !!!

Comment: Maybe it's some sort of difference in math traditions. But I think both cases can be easily distinguished when context is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also discovered this difference recently, doesn't help studying in different languages! That being said, I personally prefer the anglosaxon way X=P(B'→B)X' much easier to remember and more logical, than the French way X=P(B→B')X'. I don't know the history of it but it would be interesting to know.